Why are the plotly graphs inside the QWebEngineViewn not synched?
I based the code on from the answer in this problem text
but when i put it on a QWebEngineView from PyQt5 it doesn't synch or do anything when i pan or zoom
Python Code:
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

class SynchronizedPlotWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Crear vistas web para las gráficas
        self.graph1 = QWebEngineView()
        self.graph2 = QWebEngineView()
        self.graph3 = QWebEngineView()

        # Cargar el contenido HTML con las gráficas sincronizadas
        html_content = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Plotly Synchronized Charts</title>
            <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h2>Resize any chart, the others will get the same zoom level applied</h2>
            <div id="myDiv"></div>
            <div id="myDiv2"></div>
            <div id="myDiv3"></div>
            <script>
                var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
                var myDiv2 = document.getElementById("myDiv2");
                var myDiv3 = document.getElementById("myDiv3");
                var startTime = new Date().getTime();
                var timeStep = 60000;
                var myDivMax = 70;
                var myDiv2Max = 9000;
                var myDiv3Max = 500;

                var d3 = Plotly.d3,
                  N = 40,
                  x = d3.range(N).map(() => {
                    return new Date((startTime += timeStep));
                  }),
                  y = d3.range(N).map(() => Math.random() * myDivMax),
                  data = [{ x: x, y: y }];
                var layout = {
                  height: 200,
                  margin: { l: 45, t: 5, r: 45, b: 45 },
                  xaxis: {
                    tickfont: {
                      size: 10,
                      color: "#7f7f7f"
                    }
                  },
                  yaxis: {
                    fixedrange: true,
                    tickfont: {
                      size: 10,
                      color: "#7f7f7f"
                    }
                  }
                };
                var layout2 = {
                  height: 200,
                  margin: { l: 45, t: 5, r: 45, b: 45 },
                  xaxis: {
                    tickfont: {
                      size: 10,
                      color: "#7f7f7f"
                    }
                  },
                  yaxis: {
                    fixedrange: true,
                    tickfont: {
                      size: 10,
                      color: "#7f7f7f"
                    }
                  }
                };
                var layout3 = {
                  height: 200,
                  margin: { l: 45, t: 5, r: 45, b: 45 },
                  xaxis: {
                    tickfont: {
                      size: 10,
                      color: "#7f7f7f"
                    }
                  },
                  yaxis: {
                    fixedrange: true,
                    tickfont: {
                      size: 10,
                      color: "#7f7f7f"
                    }
                  }
                };

                Plotly.plot(myDiv, data, layout);
                var data2 = [{ x: x, y: d3.range(N).map(() => Math.random() * myDiv2Max) }];
                Plotly.plot(myDiv2, data2, layout2);
                var data3 = [{ x: x, y: d3.range(N).map(() => Math.random() * myDiv3Max) }];
                Plotly.plot(myDiv3, data3, layout3);

                var divs = [myDiv, myDiv2, myDiv3];

                function relayout(ed, divs) {
                  if (Object.entries(ed).length === 0) {return;}
                  divs.forEach((div, i) => {
                    let x = div.layout.xaxis;
                    if (ed["xaxis.autorange"] && x.autorange) return;
                    if (x.range[0] != ed["xaxis.range[0]"] ||x.range[1] != ed["xaxis.range[1]"])
                    {
                      var update = {
                      'xaxis.range[0]': ed["xaxis.range[0]"],
                      'xaxis.range[1]': ed["xaxis.range[1]"],
                      'xaxis.autorange': ed["xaxis.autorange"],
                     };
                     Plotly.relayout(div, update);
                    }
                  });
                }

                var plots = [myDiv, myDiv2, myDiv3];
                plots.forEach(div => {
                  div.on("plotly_relayout", function(ed) {
                    relayout(ed, divs);
                  });
                });
            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
        """

        # Cargar el contenido HTML en cada gráfico
        self.graph1.setHtml(html_content)
        self.graph2.setHtml(html_content)
        self.graph3.setHtml(html_content)

        # Disposición de los widgets
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.graph1)
        layout.addWidget(self.graph2)
        layout.addWidget(self.graph3)

        container = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = SynchronizedPlotWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


I already tried updating plotly and QWebEngineView and deleting cache from plotly but nothing seems to be working, when i use the html code from the original problem it works as intended

So I also had this issue, for me using dash inside the engine to manage the plots resolved all my issues.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
